# How to get programmatically the information displayed by Quick Info in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins

I searched without succes a method to get from my C# addin visual studio extension what displayed in the [Quick Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/137ey1yz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when the mouse is moved over some code element.

I hope that there's an elegant way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a code example, but found the following documentation for the [ViewFilter.HandleQuickInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.viewfilter.handlequickinfo.aspx) method which sounds like the steps you need to do.

> The base method calls the [GetCaretPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.getcaretpos.aspx) method on the [IVsTextView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.aspx) object passed to the [ViewFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.viewfilter.aspx) constructor to obtain the current caret position. This position is then passed to the OnSyncQuickInfo(IVsTextView, Int32, Int32) method on the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.source.aspx) object (obtained from the [CodeWindowManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.codewindowmanager.aspx) object in the [ViewFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.viewfilter.aspx) constructor). If OnSyncQuickInfo(IVsTextView, Int32, Int32) returns any text, this method next calls the [GetFullDataTipText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.viewfilter.getfulldatatiptext.aspx) method to get any additional information from the debugger if debugging is active. Finally, a new (or current) [TextTipData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.texttipdata.aspx) object is used to display the tool tip.

Source: [ViewFilter.HandleQuickInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.viewfilter.handlequickinfo.aspx)

**Edit:**

You can retrieve the current [IVsTextView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.aspx) using [IVsTextManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextmanager.aspx).

```
var textManager = Resolve.Service<IVsTextManager, SVsTextManager>();

IVsTextView textView;
ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(textManager.GetActiveView(fMustHaveFocus: 1, pBuffer: null, ppView: out textView));

Int32 caretRow, caretCol;
ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(textView.GetCaretPos(out caretRow, out caretCol));
```

However, I am stuck there, and unable to do anything useful with [IVsTextView.UpdateTipWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.updatetipwindow.aspx), it never calls anything on my passed dummy object, so I presume it requires an already visible IVsTipWindow from a language service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but unfortunatly I already tested this solution  without success.

Answer (score -1):

The Quickview shows the methods and properties that exists and are accessible on the class so one solution would be to use reflection to get this information.

//Gets the methods of the Class MyClass 
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Static);

Comment: Thanks but what i want is not to list all methods of a class, but get the info of the quickview,and when i move the mouse over a code element i didnt know in which class this code element exist to use your solution.